# Firebase load lada in specific range

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux-firebase

I use firebase in React.js project.
in firebase I have such collection. there nearly 400 IDs:

```
users:{
 '1JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':20,
 '2JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':8,
 '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':23
    ...........
 '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':79
 '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':23
}
```

How to make a queries to load  first 10 users, then the rest ?

I have tried with

```
limitToFirst=10
```

But cannot set range from 10 till rest.....
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `users` table structure should be like `users: { autoIncreatementedId : { id: 20}, autoIncreatementedId : { id: 8}} ...` Then you can perform `limitToFirst` query. The structure you have use `greaterThan` and `lessThan` query if you know the value.

Comment: There are quite a few questions about how to do [pagination with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20pagination). In your case, the second page would be a query with something like `ref.orderByKey().startAt(lastKeyOnPreviousPage)` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47895422/209103